# How can I display my custom model fields within the components of a modal on a website?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-14, qweb, odoo-website

I'm feeling a bit confused about how to retrieve data from my backend model and display it on my website. For instance, I'm using a drag-and-drop component provided by the website's model. How can I display data from my custom model, like images, in a carousel on the website? Additionally, I'd like to know how to submit a website form and insert the submitted data into my custom model. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Well , I'm trying to create a fully customized page for the user .

Answer (score 0):

In your custom (overriden) controller you can return request.render("a-model.view-key", data), in order to send your custom model data to the website template "a-model.view-key"... see the official website_blog addon as example:

website_blog/controllers/main.py

```py
class WebsiteBlog(http.Controller):
#...
@http.route(['''/blog/<model("blog.blog", "[('website_id', 'in', (False, current_website_id))]"):blog>/post/<model("blog.post", "[('blog_id','=',blog[0])]"):blog_post>''',
    ], type='http', auth="public", website=True)
    def blog_post(self, blog, blog_post, tag_id=None, page=1, enable_editor=None, **post):
        """ Prepare all values to display the blog.

        :return dict values: values for the templates, containing

         - 'blog_post': browse of the current post
         - 'blog': browse of the current blog
         - 'blogs': list of browse records of blogs
         - 'tag': current tag, if tag_id in parameters
         - 'tags': all tags, for tag-based navigation
         - 'pager': a pager on the comments
         - 'nav_list': a dict [year][month] for archives navigation
         - 'next_post': next blog post, to direct the user towards the next interesting post
        """
        if not blog.can_access_from_current_website():
            raise werkzeug.exceptions.NotFound()

        BlogPost = request.env['blog.post']
        date_begin, date_end = post.get('date_begin'), post.get('date_end')
        #pager = ...
        comments = blog_post.website_message_ids[pager_begin:pager_end]
        domain = request.website.website_domain()
        blogs = blog.search(domain, order="create_date, id asc")
        tag = request.env['blog.tag'].browse(int(tag_id))
        blog_url = QueryURL('', ['blog', 'tag'], blog=blog_post.blog_id, tag=tag, date_begin=date_begin, date_end=date_end)

        if not blog_post.blog_id.id == blog.id:
            return request.redirect("/blog/%s/post/%s" % (slug(blog_post.blog_id), slug(blog_post)), code=301)

        tags = request.env['blog.tag'].search([])

        # Find next Post
        blog_post_domain = [('blog_id', '=', blog.id)]
        if not request.env.user.has_group('website.group_website_designer'):
            blog_post_domain += [('post_date', '<=', fields.Datetime.now())]

        all_post = BlogPost.search(blog_post_domain)

        if blog_post not in all_post:
            return request.redirect("/blog/%s" % (slug(blog_post.blog_id)))

        # should always return at least the current post
        all_post_ids = all_post.ids
        current_blog_post_index = all_post_ids.index(blog_post.id)
        nb_posts = len(all_post_ids)
        next_post_id = all_post_ids[(current_blog_post_index + 1) % nb_posts] if nb_posts > 1 else None
        next_post = next_post_id and BlogPost.browse(next_post_id) or False

        values = {
            'tags': tags,
            'tag': tag,
            'blog': blog,
            'blog_post': blog_post,
            'blogs': blogs,
            'main_object': blog_post,
            'nav_list': self.nav_list(blog),
            'enable_editor': enable_editor,
            'next_post': next_post,
            'date': date_begin,
            'blog_url': blog_url,
             #'pager': pager,
            'comments': comments,
        }
        response = request.render("website_blog.blog_post_complete", values)

        #...
        return response
```

This controller-def returns the xml-template "blog_post_complete" (and inject its **values**: blog, tags, next_post...) which is located in the module "website_blog" under views/website_blog_templates.xml:

```xml
<template id="website_blog.blog_post_complete" name="Blog Post">
    <t t-call="website_blog.index">

        <!-- Check for active options: the stored value may be used in sub-templates too  -->
        <t t-set="opt_blog_post_readable" t-value="request.website.viewref('website_blog.opt_blog_post_readable').active"/>
        <!-- t t-set=...  -->


        <section id="o_wblog_post_top">
            <div id="title" class="blog_header" t-ignore="True">
                <t t-call="website.record_cover">
                    <t t-set="_record" t-value="blog_post"/>
                    <t t-set="use_filters" t-value="True"/>
                    <t t-set="use_size" t-value="True"/>
                    <t t-set="use_text_size" t-value="True"/>
                    <t t-set="additionnal_classes" t-value="'o_wblog_post_page_cover'"/>

                    <div class="container text-center position-relative h-100 d-flex flex-column flex-grow-1 justify-content-around">
                        <div t-attf-class="o_wblog_post_title #{opt_blog_post_select_to_tweet and 'js_tweet'} #{opt_blog_post_select_to_comment and 'js_comment'}">
                            <div t-field="blog_post.name" id="o_wblog_post_name" data-oe-expression="blog_post.name" t-att-data-blog-id="blog_post.id" placeholder="Blog Post Title"/>
                            <div t-field="blog_post.subtitle" id="o_wblog_post_subtitle"  placeholder="Subtitle"/>
                        </div>
                        <a id="o_wblog_post_content_jump" href="#o_wblog_post_main" class="css_editable_mode_hidden justify-content-center align-items-center rounded-circle mx-auto text-decoration-none">
                            <i class="fa fa-angle-down fa-3x text-white" aria-label="To blog content" title="To blog content"/>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </t>
            </div>
        </section>

        <section id="o_wblog_post_main" t-attf-class="container pt-4 pb-5 #{'anim' in request.params and 'o_wblog_post_main_transition'}">
            <!-- Sidebar-enabled Layout -->
            <div t-if="opt_blog_post_sidebar" t-attf-class="mx-auto #{opt_blog_post_readable and 'o_wblog_read_with_sidebar'}">
                <div t-attf-class="d-flex flex-column flex-lg-row #{opt_blog_post_readable and 'justify-content-between'}">
                    <div id="o_wblog_post_content" t-attf-class="#{opt_blog_post_readable and 'o_wblog_read w-100 flex-shrink-0' or 'w-lg-75'}">
                        <t t-call="website_blog.blog_post_content"/>
                    </div>
                    <div id="o_wblog_post_sidebar_col" t-attf-class="pl-lg-5 #{not opt_blog_post_readable and 'flex-grow-1 w-lg-25'}">
                        <t t-call="website_blog.blog_post_sidebar"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- No-Sidebar Layout -->
            <div t-if="not opt_blog_post_sidebar" t-attf-class="mx-auto #{opt_blog_post_readable and 'o_wblog_read'}">
                <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-lg-row">
                    <div id="o_wblog_post_content" t-attf-class=" #{opt_blog_post_readable and 'o_wblog_read w-100 flex-shrink-0'}">
                        <t t-call="website_blog.blog_post_content"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section id="o_wblog_post_footer"/>
    </t>
</template>
```

To display your custom model field, you can inherit the controller and override its def AND extend the view (using inherit_id)...

```py
from odoo.addons.website_blog.controllers.main import WebsiteBlog

class MyWebsiteBlog(WebsiteBlog):

    def blog_post(self, blog, blog_post, tag_id=None, page=1,  enable_editor=None, **post):

        #...
        # get original values from the def of the parent controller: super(MyWebsiteBlog)
        res = super(MyWebsiteBlog, self).blog_post(blog, blog_post, tag_id=None, page=1, enable_editor=None, **post)
        values = res.qcontext 
        # add your custom field value to the original values dictionary:
        values['my_custom_field'] = my_custom_value
        # pass these updated values to the original template:
        response = request.render("website_blog.blog_post_complete", values)
```